# SurfaceView doesn't display camera

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a camera on in my android app, but all I am getting is a black box where the `SurfaceView` is located.

I am using this simple XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.lazylayer.photoshoot.MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With this Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    SurfaceView surfaceView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try{
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

            String[] cameras = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
            cameraManager.openCamera(cameras[0], deviceCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}


    CameraDevice.StateCallback deviceCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            try {
                List<Surface> surfaceList = Collections.singletonList(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
                camera.createCaptureSession(surfaceList, sessionCallback, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {}
    };

    CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback sessionCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {}
    };
}
```

Here is what gets displayed when the app is ran on my phone:

[image: Result]

Comment: Have you added permission on Manifest??

Comment: I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by using a `FrameLayout` instead of a `SurfaceView`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/camera_view">
</FrameLayout>
```